# How to convert value with unicode in Json request into simple characters?

Tags: java, json, unicode, json-rpc

Sometime client send Json-RPC request with Json value as unicorde symboles.
Example:

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "add", "params": { "fields": [ { "id": 1, "val": "\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441" }, { "id": 2, "val": "\u041c\u043e\u044f" } ] }, "id": "564b0f7d-868a-4ff0-9703-17e4f768699d" }
```

How do I processing Json-RPC request:

1. My server get the request like `byte[]`;
2. Convert it to `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`;
3. Make some manipulations;
4. Save to DB;

And I found in DB records like:

```
"val": "\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441"
```

And the worst in this story. If client try to search this data, he'll get:

```
"val": "\\u0414\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0441"
```

So I think, that I need to convert request data before deserialization to JsonObject.
I tried and it **didn't** help:

```
String json = new String(incomingJsonBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
return json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Also I tried to use `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`.

**Note:** Variant with `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` I can not, because it unescape all necessary and unnecessary **'\'** symbols.

If anyone know how to solve it? Or library that already makes it?
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` depends on Jackson `ObjectMapper` to perform the actual JSON deserialization (e.g. [`io.vertx.core.json.Json`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/Json.html) has a `ObjectMapper` field). By default Jackson will convert `\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441` into `Денис`. You can verify this with a simple code snippet:

```
String json = "{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"add\", \"params\": { \"fields\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"val\": \"\\u0414\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0441\" }, { \"id\": 2, \"val\": \"\\u041c\\u043e\\u044f\" } ] }, \"id\": \"564b0f7d-868a-4ff0-9703-17e4f768699d\" }";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
System.out.println(map); // {jsonrpc=2.0, method=add, params={fields=[{id=1, val=Денис}, {id=2, val=Моя}]}, id=564b0f7d-868a-4ff0-9703-17e4f768699d}
```

Most likely the client is sending something else because your example value is deserialized correctly. Perhaps it's doubly escaped `\\u0414\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0441` value which Jackson will convert to `\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441` removing one layer of escaping?

There is no magic solution for this. Either write your own Jackson deserialization configuration or make the client stop sending garbage.

Comment: Thank you. I know that somewhere is a simple answer, but could not find it.